# LINE messaging API that can return who have read the message in group chats

Tags: callback, line-api

I currently working with line messaging API, is there any API callback that can return who has read the previous message by sending a command?

Comment: You can't .... currently, the LINE Messaging APIs and Bot SDKs do not have an endpoint to collect this data. You could try interval checks, to get the "read" trend over time. You could use external URLs and collect some external HTTP header data onclick.